# O que significa '[]s' ao final de um email?

Tags: significado, expressões

Um dos meus professores sempre encerra os emails com '[]s' .

O que significa isso? Seria um "Insira aqui a despedida que achar mais apropriada"?

Comment: [] é um abraço. []s é abraços.

Comment: Não exatamente uma pergunta (e uma resposta) sobre língua portuguesa, uma vez que tais símbolos são usados em várias línguas. São símbolos universais.

Comment: Símbolos de pontuação também são usados em várias línguas e são universais. Uma vez também são usados na comunicação em português não vejo porque não se possa perguntar a respeito. Além de que, se alguém não faz ideia do que se trata isso, e encontrou numa mensagem em português, nada mais justo de procurar num site sobre português.

Comment: @Centaurus se acha isso coloque para fechar como fora de escopo e logo se vê o que a comunidade acha. Já agora esta é a pergunta 1000.

Comment: @JorgeB.   Se você não votou para fechar, é porque não acha que deva, ou que prefere esperar que a comunidade se manifeste.  Eu também prefiro esperar a comunidade se manifestar.  Mas lembre-se, uma vez que a pergunta foi respondida, ela não pode ser fechada.

Comment: "Fora de escopo"... o nosso Jorge foi assimilado! :(

Comment: @Centaurus acho que é ao contrário - que uma vez fechada, ela não pode receber novas respostas: 1. esta tem respostas e pode-se votar nela para fechar; e 2. **[há](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes+answers%3A1)** perguntas fechadas e com respostas.

Comment: @ANeves  Uma vez que a pergunta tenha resposta, ela não pode ser deletada. (eu escrevi "fechada" mas queria dizer "deletada".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

É linguagem de Internet, pictogramas modernos:

- `[]` são abraços - duas pessoas vistas de cima, aproximando-se de braços abertos;
- `***` são beijos - cada um dos asteriscos é uns lábios franzidos num beijo;
- `o/` é um cumprimento, normalmente uma despedida - uma cabeça e um braço levantado;
- `^_^` é um sorriso - os acentos circunflexos são olhos franzidos sorridentes, e o *underscore* uma boca;
- etc.

Os "smilies" (*emoticons*) são a faceta mais reconhecida disto.

Comment: Não exatamente uma pergunta (e uma resposta) sobre língua portuguesa, uma vez que tais símbolos são usados em várias línguas.  São símbolos universais.

Comment: Não conhecia essa onda minimalista de emoticons (o/ e ^_^ eu conhecia)...pra mim 'o[ ]o' faria mais sentido, embora ambos sejam horríveis, na minha opinião.

Comment: ANeves, sabe se são todos da mesma época? `[]s` eu usava já em meados dos anos 1990..

Comment: @bfavaretto não sei, não... este meu conhecimento é empírico, e eu só comecei a usar web por volta de 2000.

Answer (score 1):

Isso é bastante usado entre programadores

Os simbolos `[]` são chamados `brackets` ou "braços"

Por isso `[]s` seria como mandar abraços assim como os brackets "abraçam" uma lista de itens, por exemplo.

```
var cesta = [banana, maçã, laranja];
```